# How can I convert a list of Genric Objects into a Map using streams and collectors

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a `List` of objects that have a generic type and want to convert it into a `Map` using streams. But I need to apply ***resolver*** to resolve the type of the argument.

**Code:**

```
private Map<String,ABCClass<?>> mapToCreate=new HashMap<>();
List<ABCClass<?>> listOfABC;

for(ABCClass<?> vals: listOfABC){
   Class<?> typeArgument=((Class<?>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(vals.getClass().getSuperClass(),ABCClass.class));
   mapToCreate.put(typeArgument.getSimpleName(),vals);
}
```

I want to convert the above code into enhanced format by using collectors and streams. Is it possible?

**I tried this:**

```
mapToCreate = listOfABC.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(((Class<?>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(listOfABC.getClass().getSuperClass(), ABCClass.class), listOfABC)));
```

I am getting an error in toMap function below line stating:

> The method toMap() in the type collectors is not applicable for the
> arguments

Comment: When you report problems like this please provide the actual error and not just the line that caused the error.  It will help others to better help you.

Comment: *Instead of for loop I want to use stream method*  Why?   Nothing wrong with using loops.

Comment: I guess its a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the code you've provided dose it's job correctly, it implies that the source list contains only one object per type, you can use `Collectors.toMap()` as shown in the code below. Otherwise, your `map.put()` is overriding values, and to resolve collisions you have to pass the third argument into `Collectors.toMap()`.

```
public Map<String, ABCClass<?>> getObjectBySimpleName(List<ABCClass<?>> listOfABC) {

    return listOfABC.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(val -> ((Class<?>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(/*...*/))
                                                        .getSimpleName(),
                                      Function.identity()));
}
```

> I am getting an error: The method toMap() in the type collectors is not applicable for the arguments

**1.** `GenericTypeResolver.resolve...etc. .getSuperClass()` is being passed as a `keyMapper` function into [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)), but it's not a **function**. The correct syntax should be like this: `x -> GenericTypeResolver.do(x)`. ([*take a look at this tutorial on lambda expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html))

**2.** You defined the map being of type `Map<String,ABCClass<?>>`, and the type returned by `getSuperClass()` doesn't match the type of key `String` and you need to apply `getSimpleName()` to fix it.